# how to compare lists whose elements are regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python

I wish to compare two lists, one list has ordinary data and the second has regular expressions  and return a match

e.g.

```
list1 = ['linux','6.0.1','mysql','5','abcd1234']

list2 = ['linux.*','6.*','mysql|python|gvim','5|6','abcd1234|efgh5678|ijkl91011']
```

I want to iterate over `list1` with the regular expressions in `list2` for a match (which in the case above would be true)

Or is there a better way to go rather than lists? if/elif is possible but messy

Comment: Sounds like a question for [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you want an item-by-item match `[ ... for (a,b) in zip(list1, list2) ]` or iterate like you said? For the above example, `zip`ing would be better I think.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction No it is **not**. Questions on code review *must* contain *complete and correct* code (if it doesn't run or if it doesn't produce the *correct* output, then it's offtopic there). In this case the OP doesn't even have an incorrect complete code.

Answer (score 5):

to find which expression matched which word you can try as below

```
list1 = ['linux','6.0.1','mysql','5','abcd1234']    
list2 = ['linux.*','6.*','mysql|python|gvim','5|6','abcd1234|efgh5678|ijkl91011']

import re    
print {i:j  for j in list1 for i in list2 if re.match(i,j)}

#output {'mysql|python|gvim': 'mysql', 'abcd1234|efgh5678|ijkl91011': 'abcd1234', '5|6': '5', 'linux.*': 'linux', '6.*': '6.0.1'}
```

other way if two or more string matches

```
list1 = ['linux','6.0.2','6.0.1','mysql','5','abcd1234']

list2 = ['linux.*','6.*','mysql|python|gvim','5|6','abcd1234|efgh5678|ijkl91011']

import re

print {i:[j  for j in list1 if re.match(i,j)] for i in list2 }

#output {
  'mysql|python|gvim': ['mysql'], 
  'abcd1234|efgh5678|ijkl91011': ['abcd1234'], 
  '5|6': ['6.0.2', '6.0.1', '5'], 
  'linux.*': ['linux'], 
   '6.*': ['6.0.2', '6.0.1']}
```

if pair wise

```
list1 = ['linux','6.0.1','mysql','5','abcd1234']

list2 = ['linux.*','6.*','mysql|python|gvim','5|6','abcd1234|efgh5678|ijkl91011']

import re

print {j:i for i,j in zip(list1,list2) if re.match(j,i) }
```

Comment: I think this is a fine solution. +1

Comment: (Not one of your voters), I think the OP might want pairwise and not all-vs-all comparison. The question is not very clear on this, but the way regexes and strings align sort of point to that.

Comment: Unclear question is not basis for -1. +1 from me for good code.